# Place object next to another in Unity and handle rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, geometry

I am trying to handle the position of a cube when I move it close to another one. When I drag a cube next to another, I want it to have the same rotation and be perfectly next to it. Here is an example of what I am trying to do :

[image]

When I drag the second square close to the one on the top, it must end up like this :

[image]

I implemented a function to clip the selected cube to another :

```
public override void clip(Cube other){
    //print("North:" + allSides[north] +" East:" + allSides[east] +" South:" + allSides[south] +" West:" + allSides[west]);
    float distX = this.transform.position.x - other.transform.position.x;
    float distZ = this.transform.position.z - other.transform.position.z;
    bool isClips = false;
    
    if(Math.Abs(distX)<2.2 && Math.Abs (distZ)< 0.5){
        transform.rotation = other.transform.rotation;
        if(distX<0){
            move(east,other.transform.position.x-SQUARE_BASE_LENGTH,other.transform.position.z,other);
        }
        if(distX>0){
            move(west,other.transform.position.x+SQUARE_BASE_LENGTH,other.transform.position.z,other);
        }
        isClips = true;
    }
    
    if(Math.Abs(distZ)<2.2 && Math.Abs (distX)< 0.5){
        transform.rotation = other.transform.rotation;
        if(distZ<0){
            move(north,other.transform.position.x,other.transform.position.z-SQUARE_BASE_LENGTH,other);
        }
        if(distZ>0){
            move(south,other.transform.position.x,other.transform.position.z+SQUARE_BASE_LENGTH,other);
        }
        isClips = true;
    }
}
```

But I have a result like this :
[image]
or[image]

depending on which side is the closest. How can I make so that my 2 cubes attach each other as expected?

Comment: You can try to make one of them parent to another and rotate parent.

Comment: That is not what i'm aiming for. People can rotate freely each square independently and the app should readapt it when they put two squares next to each others, and attach them perfectly by the closest side, how will make one parent of another fix that problem? Cause as you can see on the drawing they're not attached correctly.

Comment: Are you moving both objects or only the second one that shall attach?

Comment: @GunnarB. All objects are movable but only one at a time, and it is the moving one that has to adapt to each cube he gets close to.

Comment: Are your pivots centered on the objects or in a corner? That might get you off.

Comment: Is that `move` function doing more calculation or is it just setting stuff? That parameterlist looks rather clumsy.

Comment: You just need to know the side you are on and add the center to center distance (seems to be your edge length) to the position of the vector you want attach to.  Also, just to make sure, x and z are the correct axis? The default 2D axis are x and y.

Comment: Yes, move function does other things but for my original question only the 2nd and 3rd parameters are useful.

Comment: Ok, so the problem is that you can't just add/subtract the whole edge length on both axis. You can only do it on one (I think the one where the difference is smaller). The value on the other axis is depending on the angle.

Comment: Actually you need to calculate them both. It will only be the full edge length for one of the axis if they are directly below or aside each other (0°, 90°, ...).

Answer (score 0):

Some points for further calculation:
The diagonal distance between the two objects has to be your edge length afterwards.

Easiest would probably be to calculate the directional vector from the other into the direction you want to attach to, resize it to fit your edge length and add it to the position of the other object to get the position of the object you want attach.

You could also do some stuff with angles (sin/cos/tan) and pythagoras where the hypothenus would be your edge length, but I think this requires more calculation.